# Two divs divided by a white bar (inside a container)

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I need to make a special slideshow for my website and I need to start by "dividing a div" in 2 parts separated by a semi-transparent black or full white diagonal line (not from angle to angle, just a little bit skewed.
I searched everywhere an answer to this on the website but I can't find anything! I tried everything also but that wasn't what I wanted.
Here's a photo as a reference

[image: I can't make embed photos yet]

Comment: Thanks for the random downvote, sincerely I appreciate it... guess I'm not using this website anymore for serious questions when there are useless questions with WRONG answers, thansk and bye to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ss {
  float:left;
  width : 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px
}
section {
  position: relative
}

.separator {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc( 50% - 15px);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="one ss"></div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="two ss"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **:before** for each div you want.

you can use this code for more than 2 elemet. thas very good for slider 
and **dont need to use extra html code**. just write yor div element

```css
body{
  background-color:#999;
}
.main{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#999;
}
.div1{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.div1:before{
  content:"";
  dislpay:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:110%;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  transform:rotate(10deg);
  right:0px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
.div2{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.div2:before{
  content:"";
  dislpay:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:110%;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  transform:rotate(10deg);
  left:-20px;
  top:-5px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

see my code : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/owBOKK

Answer (score 0):

Something you want like this

```css
.container{display:block;width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;}
.left{float:left;width:45%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;}
.diagnol{float:left;width:10%;height:200px;background-color:#000;

    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(-20deg,0deg); /* Standard syntax */

}
.right{float:left;width:45%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="diagnol"></div>
<div class="right"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play a bit with the colors.

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.one {
  position: relative;
  background: darkgreen;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.one:nth-child(1):after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: darkgreen;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skew(-28deg, 0deg);
}

.two:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -25px;
  background: blue;
  transform: skew(-28deg, 0deg);
}

.two {
  width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  margin-left: 51px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="two">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```